# link click tracker - more problems

Tags: php, mysql

I got the last one to work ( [simple outbound link tracker - Why isn't this working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749116/simple-outbound-link-tracker-why-isnt-this-working/8749133#8749133) ), problems were whitespace and column name capitalization.

Now I'm trying to implement this in an existing database without any luck.

Here's the code (not including mysql connect data and obfuscating table name)

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['ID'];

/** Increase the counter of the URL to which the user is going*/
mysql_query("UPDATE `table_name` SET countout = countout + 1 WHERE ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 

/** Retrieves URL */
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

//redirects them to the link they clicked
header( "Location:" .$info['Url'] ); 
?>
```

And also important, here is a screenshot of the db table structure with data in it:

http://cl.ly/323A1i3L0n181P3H0J2B/Image%202012-01-05%20at%201.39.41%20PM.png

When I attempt

```
out.php?id=36
```

I get a blank page

**EDIT: @Runar Jørgensen provided the fix. Just trying to secure it from SQL injection now**

Comment: First, turn on error reporting. Second, come back and add the error message output to your question. Oh, and your code is massively open to **SQL Injection**.

Comment: variables are case-sensitive in php, so the second line should be `$_GET['id'];`

Comment: What happens if you do a dump on `$result`?

Comment: var_dump($result) gives(resource(2) of type (mysql result)

Comment: @AlfredoCastañedaGarcía changed to lowercase still no luck

Comment: @rdlowrey thank you, i'm novice, will research that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your script that should be corrected. You should enable errors, while developing, so that you see what's not working with your script.

First of all: Variables are case-sensitive, and if your link is `out.php?id=36` then you should use `$_GET['id']` and not `$_GET['ID']`.

Secondly: You're redirecting to an unset url, as far as see. You should edit the header tag to look like this: `header("Location: " . $row['Url']);`

You should also be aware of SQL Injections, and read up on how to handle them.

Comment: Doh. My mistake. Changed around variable names and left that part out. Thank you, those two fixed it. Now to figure out how to protect this from SQL injection. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It's several ways to protect from SQL Injections. Here's something you can read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php